# Unable to extract data from MySQL Stored procedure as source to MSSQL table using SSIS packages

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I want to load data from MySQL Stored Procedure as source to MSSQL table using SSIS package. I am using ADO.NET Source for calling stored procedure with query.

Now when I click on execute SSIS package in Visual Studio it is failing with below error:
ADONET_SRC-ExtractSql.Outputs[ADO NET Source Output]" contains no output columns. An asynchronous output must contain output columns.

[Data Flow Task with ADO.Net Source component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MP3V.png)
[Error for Source Component from Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV3YN.png)

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; you haven't defined your columns in your source node ADONET_SRC-ExtractSql.Output.

Comment: SP must perform strictly one SELECT to the output stream. Does it matches?

Answer (score 0):

It's not always possible to use stored procedures (SP) as **ADO.NET Source** inside SSIS.

First of all, check that your SP returns a single table.
Then press **Preview** when you will finish configuration of your Source. It's supposed that you will see a table filled with data.
At last, check **Input and Output Properties** of your Source in **advanced editor**. There should be any records inside **Output columns**.

Comment: Hi - Thank you for your response.
Preview is available for SP, I can see data. But in input output properties columns are not reflecting. Even if I try to add them manually it is throwing error as below: 
TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------
Error at Data Flow Task [ADO NET Source [29]]: The component does not allow adding columns to this input or output.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Pipeline component has returned HRESULT error code 0xC0208019 from a method call. (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

Comment: @ShraddhaPatle, try to change the “ValidateExternalMetadata” to FALSE (in the “Advanced Editor” dialog box) of the ADO.NET source. It will also give you metadata error, but it's OK.